# How to remove fields from collection with Lodash?

Tags: lodash

```
var characters = [
  { 'name': 'barney', 'blocked': 'a', 'employer': 'slate' },
  { 'name': 'fred', 'blocked': 'a', 'employer': 'slate' },
  { 'name': 'pebbles', 'blocked': 'a', 'employer': 'na' },
  { 'name': 'pebbles', 'blocked': 'b', 'employer': 'hanna' },
  { 'name': 'wilma', 'blocked': 'c', 'employer': 'barbera' },
  { 'name': 'bam bam', 'blocked': 'c', 'employer': 'barbera' }
];
```

Using lodash, is there an elegant way to remove specific fields from this collection?

Answer (score 3):

Simply do:

```
var filteredCollection = _.map(characters, function (c) {
    return _.omit(c, ['name']);
});
```

Now, filteredCollection no longer have the field 'name'.

Here is a [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/a4zr4ayp/).

Note:
If you use NodeJS with Mongoose v4+, you must use: _.omit(c._doc, ['name']);

Comment: well, nothing is said in the question about using mongoose :)